# Keycloak Authentication Flow

Tags: java, keycloak

How does keycloak authentication flow works behind load balancer ? For e.g., if an user is trying to authenticate his request goes to some node say node1 behind load balancer and it sends response back saying you are authenticated and then again when trying to access any url it sends the response to node2, how does node2 get to know that the user is authenticated and authorized to see the page without asking him to login again ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the official documentation by Keycloak, which you can find [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, but unable to find the answer. Or if it's there where is it residing ?

Comment: Sessions are stored in cache. You can replicate them for clustered environments: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html/server_installation_and_configuration_guide/server_cache_configuration